# How to turn a git repository into a single .diff file that can be applied with patch

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have multiple git repositories and would like to generate a big .diff file for each repository.

This .diff patch would then be applied by a customer using something like the 'patch' utility to generate the files in the repository minus git history.

Does anyone know how I would be able to do this?

Thanks for your time,
Matt

Comment: `diff` against what? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but wouldn't a simple zip from a checkout of the branch you want, excluding the `.git` dir, work?

Comment: I don't want to deliver the files themselves - I want a patch that creates the files when applied - also a zip would contain history

Comment: That's what I don't understand. You want to generate a diff against nothing, so as to have one diff file that will re-create everything, instead of a plain zip/tar/archive? The zip would not contain  history if you exclude `.git`.

Comment: Yep that's correct I want to create a diff against nothing.
For some projects there are two refs in git that I can diff but for some other projects (the focus of this question) there is not so I would like a diff against nothing so that I can deliver them in the same format

Answer (score 1):

If you want to diff against nothing...why not just do that?

```
$ mkdir empty
$ ls
empty myproject
$ diff -ruN empty myproject > diff-against-nothing.patch
```

Answer (score 1):

git diff 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 > diff-against-nothing.patch
I discovered git's magic empty SHA1!